# Is there a good way to make onclick="" conditional based on size?

Tags: javascript

I don't want to trigger the link thats inside onclick="" when the site is inside a big screen.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/LasCrucesOralFacialSurgery/" onclick="window.open('fb://profile/163825970332372')">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: You could use multiple links with css media queries to only show the appropriate ones, or change `onclick` to some js function that will check the screen size before performing the appropriate action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a funtion in which you check the screen size and if it has the size you want then trigger the "window.open" or not

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/LasCrucesOralFacialSurgery/" onclick="getScreenSize()">Facebook</a>
```

and in your javascript code

```
function getScreenSize() {
    // in pixels
    if ( screen.width < 400 || screen.height < 400)
        window.open('fb://profile/163825970332372')
}
```

For more info on the screen object: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp

Comment: @user6146289 glad it helped, would you mind marking the answer as the solution for your question :), thanks!